# Display two different images of a table as a single table in Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I am trying to place two images of a table side-by-side so that it looks as a single table. The sizes of both the tables are different. I took a linear layout and placed both the images in it and set the dimensions manually but cannot get the required look. Is there any way to make them look like a single image? And is there any way any way to zoom the image to have a clear look at data?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">`enter code here`

        <ImageView
            style="@style/TableImageViewStyle"
            android:src="@drawable/autobrands_table2_left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <ImageView
            style="@style/TableImageViewStyle"
            android:src="@drawable/autobrands_table2_right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

TableImageViewStyle

```
<......>

<style name="TableImageViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:gravity="right">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/autobrands_table2_left"
        style="@style/TableImageViewStyle" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:gravity="left">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        style="@style/TableImageViewStyle"
        android:src="@drawable/autobrands_table2_right"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

if u want image should fill area of image view use **background** insted **src**